# Datetime.now returns next year's date

Tags: apex

I am using the formulae:

```
myDatetime = Datetime.now();
myDatetimeStr = myDatetime.format('dd/MM/YYYY');
```

[image]

But the values I get are next' year's date.

```
13:37:40:000 USER_DEBUG   "Close Date" : "29/12/2016",
```

How is that even possible that the : DateTime.now() is so wrong?

Debug logs are even more crazy :-/

> 14:19:22.746
>   (746983721)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[163]|myDatetime|Datetime|false|false
>   14:19:22.747
>   (747018312)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[163]|**myDatetime|"2015-12-29T00:00:00.000Z**"
>   14:19:22.747 (747028286)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[164] 14:19:22.747
>   (747037545)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[164]|Bytes:10 14:19:22.747
>   (747137413)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[164]|Bytes:10 14:19:22.747
>   (747169556)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[164]|myDatetimeStr|String|false|false
>   14:19:22.747
>   (747188016)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[164]|**myDatetimeStr|"29/12/2016**"

Comment: check if you are adding something like `addyear()`

Comment: thanks, not adding anything, simple 2 liner code. added debug log output to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use small `y` instead of capital `Y`

```
Datetime myDatetime = Datetime.now();
String myDatetimeStr = myDatetime.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
system.debug('=========='+myDatetimeStr);
```

---

IF you looked into this link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

> The capital Y merge field is the WEEK YEAR - which from the 27th
>   December 2015 is IN 2016!
>
> The lower case y merge field is the CALENDAR YEAR - which will be 2015
>   as expected.